# How to search through 1000 stored procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Currently I have a database with nearly 1000 stored procedures. Whenever I need to check for any stored procedure, it takes a lot of time. Is there a way to search / browse the required stored procedure by just typing the name of stored procedure?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "search/browse the required SP"? Do you know the name of the SP you need and want to look at the code, or do you need to find the SP without knowing the name?

Comment: @Raj currently i have to open server explorer and start checking from start to last for SP whose name may be different,but is there any technique to find SP easily or search them easily ..like typing and hitting search

Comment: Do you want to just identify the SP or do you want to look at the code of the SP?

Comment: yes..i need to look the code

Comment: RedGate SQL Search (Free)? Note: I don't work for them, just use their product

Comment: @Greg not good ,redgate search ?any drawbacks ?

Comment: @utility I use it and don't have any problems with it. I highly recommend it - and it's free. Just wanted to point out I have no affiliation with them, they just make awesome stuff and I think SQL Search will do what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Select **Store Prcedure Folder**

2)Than **Click On Filter** button AS Shown in Image

3)Than Enter SP name and Click On **OK** Button

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [3rd party add in to ssms](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1LENP_enIL564IL564&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ssms%20search%20addin) to search your database, or you can query [`sys.procedures`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188737.aspx)
to view the content of a procedure you can execute [`sp_helptext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx) like this:
`EXEC sp_helptext '<Your stored procedure name>'`

Comment: I didn't want to recommend a specific 3rd party tool in my answer, so it would not be considered as spam. If you think it's wrong to recommend it in a comment, please flag it so that a moderator will decide if it should be deleted. my recommendation is [red gate's sql search 2.](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) it's free and I've have a good experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM [sys].[procedures] WHERE [NAME] = 'YOUR_SP_NAME'

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysobjects] WHERE [XType] = 'P' AND [NAME] = 'YOUR_SP_NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Object Explorer:**

**Step1:**
Right Click on Stored Procedures category in required database and **select Filter > Filter Settings:**

[image]

**Step 2:** 
In the Filter Settings dialog box, specify "Sales" in Value field, and click on OK to apply filter

[image]

After applying this filer Object Explorer will only show stored procedures matching the specified filter criteria, only those which have word "Sales" in their name in this case:

[image]

**Step 3:** To clear the filter and list all objects again, right click on filtered category and **select Filter > Remove Filter**. This will clear the filter applied.